# ngModel and ngRepeat and access to properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items()">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="anObject[item.name]">
</div>
```

I want to access a property dependent on the `item.name` in my `$scope.anObject` that I have defined in my controller.
How would I do it? The above try does not work and nor does the following one.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items()">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="anObject.{{item.name}}">
</div>
```

**EDIT**: [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/my3kozuf/2/)

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="anObject[item.name]">` should work

Comment: well the error message is *Cannot assign to read only property 'Apple' of true*

Comment: Cant really be sure need more code - however make a little plunker and see if what your looking is possible - its should work

Comment: Okay added a Fiddle. When checking one of the boxes, the console just explodes. I would expect that the string `'i like apples'` would be overwritten with either `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the `items()` function which returns the array and the `ng-repeat` you got a recursion. This breaks the `$digest` cycle. If you don't return the array and just bind it to a scope variable it works like a charm ;)

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/my3kozuf/5/).

Comment: Yes... This fixes this fiddle. Problem stays in my original code however. This does not help me much :/

Comment: Well, you asked for help with this example and you got it.

Comment: However... I it's not possible to go with my whole code into a fiddle... So I'll leave it with that and will find a workaround.